# What’s the alternative for 'Publishers.Once'?

Tags: swift, combine

The new Xcode 11 beta 4 has removed `Publishers.Once` struct from the Combine framework. What is the alternative?

`Just` seems the likely candidate, however, it cannot be used for returning a publisher in methods with return type `AnyPublisher<Bool, Error>` as the associated `Failure` type for `Just` [is `Never`.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/just/failure)

For example in the following method, I could return a `Publishers.Once` since the associated `Failure` type wasn't `Never`.

```
func startSignIn() -> AnyPublisher<Void, Error> {
    if authentication.provider == .apple { 
        let request = ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider().createRequest()
        request.requestedScopes = [.email, .fullName]

        let controller = ASAuthorizationController(authorizationRequests: [request])
        controller.delegate = self
        controller.performRequests()

        return Publishers.Once(()).eraseToAnyPublisher()
    } else {
        return SignInManager.service.startSignIn(auth: authentication)
            .map { (auth) -> Void in
                self.authentication = auth
        }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

But now when I change it back to `Just` I get a compile error complaining that `Just` cannot be returned since the method should return a publisher with an associated `Failure` type.

```
func startSignIn() -> AnyPublisher<Void, Error> {
    if authentication.provider == .apple { 
        let request = ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider().createRequest()
        request.requestedScopes = [.email, .fullName]

        let controller = ASAuthorizationController(authorizationRequests: [request])
        controller.delegate = self
        controller.performRequests()

        return Just(()).eraseToAnyPublisher() //Error Here
    } else {
        return SignInManager.service.startSignIn(auth: authentication)
            .map { (auth) -> Void in
                self.authentication = auth
        }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

Isn't there any alternative to `Publishers.Once` which can also have associated failure types?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In Xcode 11 beta 4, `Publishers.Once` was renamed `Result.Publisher` (where `Result` is part of the standard library). So write this instead:

```
return Result.Publisher(()).eraseToAnyPublisher()
```

Apple also added a `publisher` property to `Result`, which is convenient if you already have a `Result`:

```
let result: Result<Void, Error> = someFunction()
return result.publisher.eraseToAnyPublisher()
```

Comment: Thank you very much, been looking for this for 2 days.

Answer (score 5):

`setFailureType(to:)` could be a solution for some paticular cases:

```swift
return Just(()).setFailureType(to: Error.self).eraseToAnyPublisher()
```

But please note that Rob's answer is generally preferable. That is simpler and probably faster.